# Using a conditional categorical distribution in simstudy (R)

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to implement a conditional categorical distribution using the simstudy package in R. Yet, when I try to add the conditional variable I get the following error:

> Error: Categorical distribution requires 2 or more probabilities

Adding a categorical variable before creating the data works. A minimum working example is given here:

```
library(simstudy)
def <- defData(varname = "xNr", dist = "nonrandom", formula=7, id = "idnum")
def <- defData(def, varname = "contributor", dist = "categorical", formula = ".5;.5")
dt <- genData(8430, def)
def.target <- defCondition(condition = "contributor == 1", dist = "categorical", formula = ".1;.15;.4;.35")
dt <- addCondition(def.target, dt, "target")
```

Comment: If you already have a workaround, then why aren't you emailing the package maintainer?

Comment: This is a misunderstanding. Categorical distributions generally aren't a problem. Adding a conditional categorical distribution doesn't work. Sorry.